# NSAutoreleasePool with Json Data

Tags: objective-c, json, memory-management

Just need to know if I'm doing something wrong in this code. my app seem work fast now with this code. I just want to if i really understant that

```
   - (void)receive
{


    NSString *post2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"expediteur=%@&destinataire=%@",
                       [[expediteurLbl text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
                       [[destinataireLbl text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData *dataToSend2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:[post2 UTF8String] length:[post2 length]  ];

    request2 = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request2 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/****************.php"]];
    [request2 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request2 setHTTPBody:dataToSend2];
    [request2 setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(displayView) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; 

    }

    -(void)displayView

    {
        NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSURLResponse *response2;
        NSError *error2;
        NSData *data2 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request2 returningResponse:&response2 error:&error2];
        reponseServeur2= [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:data2 encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];



        responseString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [[reponseServeur2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"  withString:@""] mutableCopy];


        self.messageArray = [responseString2 JSONValue];
        [messTableView reloadData];




        [pool release];


    }
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(receive) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: i don't have errors but in console somes warnings "NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4e45ab0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking".

Comment: You're not autoreleasing any objects inside the autorelease pool, so why have you used it inside `displayView`?

Comment: i can not release NSArray?

Comment: What array? The only array there *might* be is `self.messageArray`. Looks like you've synthesized that property, so you'll only need to release it in your `dealloc` method if you're using `retain` or `copy` on the property.

Comment: ok i understand. but I 'trying to do a thread not to slow down the application

Comment: Yeah, but you're calling UI methods (`reloadData`) in a thread that is not the main thread - and that is a bad thing.

Comment: @Alex There are many autoreleased objects in both `receive` and `displayView`, including the NSData returned by `sendSynchronousRequest`, the object returned by `JSONValue`, and several others.

Answer (score 2):

I gather that `request2` is an instance variable?  It's risky at best to set it with an autoreleased value and then expect it to be valid later in your `displayView` method.

But it probably works because you execute `receive` in a background task, and background tasks have no default autorelease pool.  If it weren't for that `request2` would likely go "poof" before it got to `displayView`.

So all of the autoreleased data items in `receive` -- post2, dataToSend2, request2, several temporary strings, and at least one temporary URL -- are leaking.

Answer (score 1):

> Just need to know if I'm doing something wrong in this code.

The short answer is YES.

1. request2 is allocated and autoreleased in a different thread than its referenced and may be dealloc'd before you get to use it in displayView.  This would be a 'race condition' and you probably won't see it happen consistently, but it'll crash the app when it does happen.
2. `reponseServeur2` and `responseString2` are never released (or autoreleased) at all.  These are memory leaks
3. The line `[[reponseServeur2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n"  withString:@""] mutableCopy];` does nothing.  You'd want to assign the result of that expression to some variable.
4. You appear to repeat the sequence:

   ```
   self.messageArray = [responseString2 JSONValue];
   [messTableView reloadData];
   ```

   which is probably just a typo.
5. Everything in `receive` is happening without an Autorelease pool, so `post2`, `dataToSend2`, and `request2` will leak.  The warning you report is for `post2`, probably.  Minimally, you need to wrap the contents of `receive` in an NSAutoreleasePool just like `displayView`.

Comment: ok thk for answer but i m sorry i m  dropped :( . i try to something to use receveive in background for not slowing the app

Comment: 6. You shouldn't be updating the view from your thread;  the UIKit is generally main-thread-only unless explicitly documented otherwise.